# How to scrape all review product using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

right now im doing scrape review product at this website
https://www.lazada.com.my/products/xiaomi-mi-a1-4gb-ram-32gb-rom-i253761547-s336359472.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlistcategory.list.64.71546883QBZiNT&search=1

i manage to get the review on first page only

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen as uReq #package web scraping
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def make_soup(website) :
req =  Request(website,headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
uClient = uReq(req)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
return page_soup
lazada_url = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/products/xiaomi-mi-a1-4gb-ram-32gb-rom-i253761547-s336359472.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlistcategory.list.64.71546883QBZiNT&search=1'

website = make_soup(lazada_url)
news_headlines = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['reviews','sentiment','score'])
headlines = website.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"item-content"})
n = 0
for item in headlines :
    top = item.div
    #print(top)
    #print()
    text_headlines = top.text
    print(text_headlines)
    print()
    n +=1
    news_headlines.loc[n-1,'title'] = text_headlines
```

Result only first page.. How to do for all pages. there is no pages in the Url for me to loop.. you guys can check the url.. Thank You :)

```
I like this phone very much and it's global version. I recommend this phone for who like gaming. Delivery just took 3 days only. Thanks Lazada

Item was received in just two days and was wonderfully wrapped. Thanks for the excellent services Lazada!

Very happy with the phone. It's original, it arrived in good condition. Built quality is superb for a budget phone.

The delivery is very fast just take one day to reach at my home. However, the tax invoice is not attached. How do I get the tax invoice?

great deal from lazada. anyway, i do not find any tax invoice. please do email me the tax invoice. thank you.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scrape the pagination at the bottom of the reviews to find the minimum and maximum number of reviews:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def get_page_reviews(content:soup) -> dict:
  rs = content.find('div', {'class':'mod-reviews'}).find_all('div', {'class':'item'})
  reviews = [i.find('div', {'class':'item-content'}).find('div', {'class':'content'}).text for i in rs]
  stars = [len(c.find('div', {'class':'top'}).find_all('img')) for c in rs]
  _by = [i.find('div', {'class':'middle'}).find('span').text for i in rs]
  return {'stars':stars, 'reviews':reviews, 'authors':_by}

d = soup(requests.get('https://www.lazada.com.my/products/xiaomi-mi-a1-4gb-ram-32gb-rom-i253761547-s336359472.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlistcategory.list.64.71546883QBZiNT&search=1').text, 'html.parser')
results = list(map(int, filter(None, [i.text for i in d.find_all('button', {'class':'next-pagination-item'})])))
for i in range(min(results), max(results)+1):
  new_url = f'https://www.lazada.com.my/products/xiaomi-mi-a1-4gb-ram-32gb-rom-i253761547-s336359472.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlistcategory.list.64.71546883QBZiNT&search={i}'
  #now, can use new_url to request the next page of reviews
  r = get_page_reviews(soup(requests.get(new_url).text, 'html.parser'))
  final_result = [{'stars':a, 'author':b, 'review':c} for a, b, c in zip(r['stars'], r['authors'], r['reviews'])]
```

Output (for first page):

```
[{'stars': 5, 'author': 'by Ridwan R.', 'review': "I like this phone very much and it's global version. I recommend this phone for who like gaming. Delivery just took 3 days only. Thanks Lazada"}, {'stars': 5, 'author': 'by Razli A.', 'review': 'Item was received in just two days and was wonderfully wrapped. Thanks for the excellent services Lazada!'}, {'stars': 5, 'author': 'by Nur F.', 'review': "Very happy with the phone. It's original, it arrived in good condition. Built quality is superb for a budget phone."}, {'stars': 5, 'author': 'by Muhammad S.', 'review': 'The delivery is very fast just take one day to reach at my home. However, the tax invoice is not attached. How do I get the tax invoice?'}, {'stars': 5, 'author': 'by Xavier Y.', 'review': 'great deal from lazada. anyway, i do not find any tax invoice. please do email me the tax invoice. thank you.'}]
```

Comment: I try and got error with this one.. helps me :(

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-ad497856f5a5> in <module>()
 
---> 17     r = get_page_reviews(soup(requests.get(new_url), 'html.parser'))
    
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: @moxasya Please try now.

Comment: wow.. that's work but it keeps loop same review because of page navigation review not in url
[link]https://www.lazada.com.my/products/xiaomi-mi-a1-4gb-ram-32gb-rom-i253761547-s336359472.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlistcategory.list.64.71546883QBZiNT&search=1
[link]https://www.lazada.com.my/products/xiaomi-mi-a1-4gb-ram-32gb-rom-i253761547-s336359472.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlistcategory.list.64.71546883QBZiNT&search=2
[link]https://www.lazada.com.my/products/xiaomi-mi-a1-4gb-ram-32gb-rom-i253761547-s336359472.html?spm=a2o4k.searchlistcategory.list.64.71546883QBZiNT&search=3

as u try link goes page1

Comment: link....search{1} , search{2}, search{3} 
the url still show the page 1 of review..

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is just using `click()` method in `Selenium`.

`Selenium` is a portable software-testing framework for web applications that allows you to access the web and get the sources you want.

In the given URL, there are pages button for the review, so just find the buttons by `xpath`, `class`, `id` by using `find_element_by_(anything you want).click()`. This will lead you to next pages.

This is the sample code of mine :D

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


url = 'https://www.lazada.com.my/products/xiaomi-mi-a1-4gb-ram-32gb- rom-i253761547-s336359472.html? spm=a2o4k.searchlistcategory.list.64.71546883QBZiNT&search=1'

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/baejihwan/Documents/chromedriver', 
chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(0.1)

page_soup = soup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
headlines = page_soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"item-content"})

for item in headlines :
    top = item.div
    text_headlines = top.text
    print(text_headlines)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//* .[@id="module_product_review"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/button[2]').click()

page_soups = soup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
headline = page_soups.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"item-content"})

for item in headline:
    top = item.div
    text_headlines = top.text
    print(text_headlines)
```

**Output**:

```
I like this phone very much and it's global version. I recommend this phone for who like gaming. Delivery just took 3 days only. Thanks Lazada

Item was received in just two days and was wonderfully wrapped. Thanks for the excellent services Lazada!

Very happy with the phone. It's original, it arrived in good condition. Built quality is superb for a budget phone.

The delivery is very fast just take one day to reach at my home. However, the tax invoice is not attached. How do I get the tax invoice?

great deal from lazada. anyway, i do not find any tax invoice. please do email me the tax invoice. thank you.

Penghantaran cepat. Order ahad malam, sampai rabu pagi. Tu pun sbb selasa cuti umum. 
Fon disealed dgn bubble wrap dan box.
Dah check mmg original malaysia.
Dpt free tempered glass. Ok je.
Fon so far pakai ok.
Selama ni pakai iphone, bila pakai android ni kekok sikit. 
invoice tidak disertakan.
battery dia dikira cpt juga hbs.. 

Saya telah beli smartphone xioami mi a1 dan telah terima hari ni. Tetapi telefon itu telah rosak. Tidak dapat on.

beli pada 1/6 dgn harga rm599 dpt free gift usb otg type c 64gb jenama sandisk.
delivery pantas, order 1/6 sampai 4/6 tu pon sebab weekend ja kalau x mesti order harini esk sampai dah.
packaging terbaik, dalam kotak ada air bag so memang secure.
kotak fon sealed, dlm kotak dapat screen protector biasa free, kabel type c dgn charger 3 pin.
keluar kotak terus update ke Android oreo, memang puas hati la overall. memang berbaloi sangat beli. Kudos to lazada.

i submitted the order on on sunday and i get it tuesday morning, even the despatch guy called me at 830am just to make sure if im already at the office. super reliable. for the phone, well i got it for RM599. what could you possibly asked for more? hehehe

Purchased Xiaomi Mi A1 from Official store with an offer of "Free gift SanDisk Ultra 64GB Dual USB Drive 3.0 OTG Type C Flash Drive". But they delivered only USB drive 2.0
```

I've tried it in extremely naive way! It will be better to define a function that reads in html codes and parse the data you want. This code only parse the review to page 2, and you can modify it to get all the reviews to the end! :D If you have questions about this code, please leave a comment!

Hope this helps!

Comment: i already run your code but got error with this InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //* .[@id="module_product_review"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/button[5] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//* .[@id="module_product_review"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/button[5]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Comment: Oh do you have a chrome driver installed?

Comment: Xpath might differ by the browser you use.

Comment: Yes i have install chrome driver.. i run it and did pop up the chrome.. first page scrap result show..but error for next.. whats mean by Xpath.. im new to selenium.. never use it before ;)

Comment: If you click `f12`, then developer mode console shows up!

Comment: If you click in the page button 2, and left click on mouse will open you a `Copy` section, which has `Copy Xpath` in it!